# Query for average of last 20 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, sql-server-2008

I have the following table (called: daily):

```
daily_id,  symbol_id,  date,        volume
1          555         2015-01-21   3466
2          444         2015-01-21   54645
3          555         2015-01-22   4656
4          444         2015-01-22   546468
```

I am trying to write a query that will give me the average volume per symbol for the last 20 days. i.e.: I need to average volume for symbol 555 for the last 20 days, and the same for symbol 444. I then need to select the top 100 symbols with the highest average volume.

I have only been able to determine the average volume per symbol for the entire history of the symbol, but I haven't been able to figure out how to limit the lookback period:

```
select avg(volume) as avg_vol, symbol_id
from daily
group by symbol_id;
```

Once I have that, I need to limit the results to the top 100 symbols with the highest average volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `INTERVAL`

```
SELECT AVG(volume) AS avg_vol, symbol_id
FROM daily
WHERE date > current_date - INTERVAL'20' day
GROUP BY symbol_id
ORDER BY AVG(volume) DESC
LIMIT 100;
```